# Getting error while creating type "table" in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2

I am creating a type as table and the query is as:

```
create type dbo.Tbl as table(Country_Code varchar(5), 
                             Country_Name varchar(150),
                             Country_Capital varchar(150),
                             Continent_Code char(2)
                            );
```

but when I execute it, I get an error:

> Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 1
>   Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'as'.

Please suggest a solution

Comment: What **version** of the SQL Server engine are you running against? What does `SELECT @@VERSION` return? Seems you're running against an older version that doesn't support user-defined table types ....

Comment: Your code works on a SQL Server 2008 R2 (as tagged). A new user-defined table type is being created, even with `AS`.

Comment: sorry guys i should have checked the version before it's 2005... :(